# WP get_field or the_field sometimes doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I use the ACF plugin to add domains to my Wordpress site. This plugin also works well with some tags, while others don't.

For example, when I enter the first telefon value, it works without problems, but when I update the telefon again, the plugin does not work

Picture
[The field above the red line is the value I entered first, the field below the red line is the second value I entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj702.png)

When I enter the first value, I can see the telefon value on the site, while the second time I change it, the telefon value remains the same as the first value.

The code I wrote on my website is below.

```
<a href="tel: " class="site-footer-link">
  <?php the_field('telefon') ?>
</a>
```

The label I made in the ACF is as follows.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw1Vn.png)

Can you tell me what the problem is caused by?
Sorry for my bad english by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you haven't included the phone number in the 'href' attribute of the tag. I would implement it like this:

```
<?php
$telefon = get_field('telefon');
if( !empty($telefon) ){
    $telefon_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $telefon);
    ?>
    <a href="tel:+<?php echo $telefon_number; ?>" class="site-footer-link">
       <?php echo $telefon; ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave, but there is no change, the label that should be written on the button is no longer written.
I'm doing it for the footer. Do I need to use a different code for the footer?

Comment: Perhaps your theme is executing a custom WP_Query, and after that, there should be a function [wp_reset_postdata();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/). If this function is not used, you won't be able to retrieve the correct custom field. This function restores the `$post` global to the current post in the main query. Therefore, you need to check all instances where you use WP_Query and make sure to include `wp_reset_postdata()` afterward.

Comment: Additionally, you can test this theory quickly by placing this function before my code. However, I recommend following the initial advice and revisiting all WP_Query instances. This is crucial as it can resolve many potential bugs in the future.

Comment: wp_reset_postdata(); I tried the command. This code worked for my home page, but not for my about page or services page. It just helped me bring up the footer information from the home page.

I am translating the HTML page into a wordpress page. Like most people who code with PHP. Can WP_Query be in places where I don't write?

Comment: I think the tags I create here are local variables, I try to use them globally. According to my research, the ACF provides this with the "options page". This is also available in the pro version. Can't we use it without a pro? Or am I moving in the wrong place :)

Comment: You can use it globally by simply adding the page's ID (where the phone was listed) to the following parameter of the get_field() function. For example, like this: `$telefon = get_field('telefon', 1234);`

Comment: Thank you, it's happened now. When I do as you say now, I can see the footer information on the about and services pages